# Why my CORS application doesn't recognize my session?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, cors

I've been trying to setup CORS in my Angular client-side and Laravel server-side app, in order to debug it. I've done it before without problems, but for an extraneous reason this is not working now, and I don't know why.

I tried using [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) and now I'm trying with a custom middleware in Laravel, anyways the result is exactly the same.

I can send CORS petitions to the server, and I can login into. But once I'm there, the server is not able to detect that I'm already logged in.

I've already set the following in my angular application. (In fact I never did this with my other apps, but read that I might need the following).

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
});
```

But I keep getting a 302 response (redirect) from Laravel to the OPTIONS request sent by the Angular app. Meaning that I'm not logged into the app (which in fact I did).

An image explains it better, here's the **failed authentication with CORS**:
[image: Failed CORS]

And here is the **working authentication with CORS** (I think I did mostly the same in both, but one works and the other don't):
[image: Working CORS]

I should add that this is not a session problem, as this works without CORS (On a Webview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an eon trying to make it work, I found out that my app was not able to process the Session on Preflight, so I ended up sending an empty answer to the OPTIONS request, with the appropriate headers.

I'll POST my CORS middleware here, you can use it, as is dedicated to the public domain under CC0.

```
<?php

// Under Public Domain Dedication <https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/>
// With help of the following article: http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $VALID_ORIGINS = ['*'];

        foreach($VALID_ORIGINS as $valid_origin){
            if($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']===$valid_origin||$valid_origin==='*'){
                if($request->method()=='OPTIONS'){
                    return response()->make()
                        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])
                        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Content-Type')
                        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
                }else{
                    return $next($request)
                        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])
                        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```